# Angular2 - HTTP 200 treated as error

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, asp.net-web-api2, response

I am trying to get Angular2 to work with my Asp.Net WebApi 2 server. I managed to handle some GET requests correctly, however this POST request behaves strangely. I receive an OK (200) response from my server, yet the following code treats it as an error:

```
public Register(){
    this.accountService.Register(this.Name, this.Password, this.RepeatPassword, this.Email, this.Skype, this.Website).subscribe(
        () => {      //this is what's supposed to be called, but isn't
            this.accountService.Login(this.Name, this.Password).subscribe(
                res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    localStorage.setItem('token', res);
                    localStorage.setItem('user', this.Name);
                    this.router.navigate(['Home']);
                },
                error2 => {
                    console.log(error2.Message);
                }
            );
        },
        error => { //the response gets here, instead of being handled above
            console.log(error.Message);
        }
    );
}
```

Here is the Register method of the accountService:

```
public Register (userName:string, password:string, confirmPassword:string, email:string, skype:string, website:string)
{
    return this.http.post(this.Uri + 'api/Account/Register', JSON.stringify(
        {
            UserName: userName,
            Password: password,
            ConfirmPassword: confirmPassword,
            Email: email,
            Skype: skype,
            Website: website
        }), this.GetRequestOptions() ).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally found the answer.
Ajax, when it's expecting a json, fires off the error callback after getting HTTP 200 with a malformed json (including an empty file). The fix was to replace all empty responses with {}.

To do this in a ASP.Net WebApi2 server, you need to use `return Ok("{}");` instead of just `return Ok();` at the end of the method being called.

An alternative solution (and most likely a better one) is to change the calling code - in particular, `.map((res: Response) => res.json())` is the bit of code that failed - a conditional checking if `res` is empty could be added before calling `res.json()`.

Comment: Could you show your fix in code? Running through similar issue too.

Comment: It works like a charm. My API endpoint returns just a string, while by default in Angular post method response is expected to be 'JSON'. Changed the response type to 'text' and finally, it works correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem here. But in my case it was that I forgot to tell Angular which kind of response my endpoint was sending. For more information you can read [the GreyBeardedGeek response at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605619/angular-6-httperrorresponse-on-post-with-200-status).