# Angular 6 HttpErrorResponse on POST with 200 status

Tags: angular, api, post

With my Angular 6 client I access the `http://localhost:8082/login` to send `username` and `password` and return a token. 
This is the error [image]
Notice that, under `error:` there is the token that I want.

This is how it looks on Postman
[image]

And this is the function I use on Angular to get the token with the given username and password

```
validateUser(user:User){


    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','No-Auth':'True' });



    return this.httpClient.post<User>(this.apiURL + '/login',user,{headers:reqHeader});
  }
```

I want just to return the token, like in Postman. I tried `toPromise()` but I've got even more errors.

Comment: Please check content-type is valid or not

Comment: Content-type is application/json in angular as well

Comment: You are trying to parse the response which is not JSON and thereby getting error. Either send the token in JSON string or change headers to solve the issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, the Angular HttpClient tries to parse the body of the HTTP response as JSON.
Since the response body that you are receiving is plain text, e.g. "Bearer .....", and not JSON, the JSON parse is failing.

You need to tell the HttpClient to expect a plain text response, like this:

```
this.httpClient.post(this.apiURL + '/login', user, {headers:reqHeader, responseType: 'text'});
```

Also note that since the response is a string, you should not be trying to cast it to a User (don't do the `<User>` bit); The outgoing message is the User, the return value is a string.

Comment: This is it! Thank you sir!

Comment: Thank you. Happened same with me. Lack of attention.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 11+ use  httpOptions = {
responseType: 'text' as const,
}

Answer (score 0):

i have the same error

you must change the response from json to text

datatype by default is JSON

this way make new error in observable and the solution of this case

```
this.httpClient.post(this.apiURL + '/login', user, {headers:reqHeader, responseType: 'text'});
```

in a above  way i think will make new error because  observable and the solution in this case

> ERROR in src/app/myS.service.ts(24,54): error TS2322: Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

you must use this pattern to solution it

```
    returnObservable(): Observable<any> {
  const requestOptions: Object = {
    /* other options here */
    headers:reqHeader
    responseType: 'text'
  }
  return this.http.get<any>(url, body, requestOptions);
}
```