# Angular observable throws error with status code 200 when trying to get multiple images

Tags: javascript, angular, postgresql, express

### Problem description

I'm a having problems with getting multiple images from a postgreSQL database and showing it on my frontend. The images are stored in postgreSQL as binary data. If I run my express code I get the image data as buffer back in json format.
When I run the code I receive a 200 status code, but the observable ends up executing the handleError function.
Here you can see my console --> [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BW5A.png)

### My goal

I want to get multiple images from a house to show on my frontend modal page, those images are stored in a separate table in the database. With this query `("select * from housee.houses_images where straatnaam = $1 AND straatnr = $2 AND postcode = $3",)`  in my postgreSQL database I can get the right images. After I get all the images I want to display them in a ion-img tag (from the ionic framework)

### Code information

So I am using a **postgresSQL** database with a backend in javascript using the **express.js** library and a frontend in **Angular**.

This is my table in postgreSQL--> [table postgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l49Jw.png)

In my **backend index.js** file I have this code

```
 app.get(
  "/getMarkerPhotos/:straatnaam/:straatnr/:postcode",
  function (req, res) {
    client.query(
      "select * from housee.houses_images where straatnaam = $1 AND straatnr = $2 AND postcode = $3",
      [req.params.straatnaam, req.params.straatnr, req.params.postcode],
      function (err, data) {
        if (err != null) {
          res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(200);
        }
      }
    );
  }
);
```

The call in the backend is working because if I run it in postman it gives back my data in JSON format --> [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lco0.png)

On to the frontend, in my **api.service.ts** file I made this function

```
getMarkerPhotos(straatnaam: any, straatnr: any, postcode: any): Observable<any> {
    var result = this.http.get(this.url + '/getMarkerPhotos/' + straatnaam + '/' + straatnr + '/' + postcode)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
   );
    console.log(result)
    return result
  }

<--other code-->

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };
```

Than on my modal page (**maker-modal.components.ts**) where I want to show the images from the database I have this code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getMarkerPhotos();
  }

  getMarkerPhotos() {
    this.api.getMarkerPhotos(this.straatnaam, this.straatnr, this.postcode).subscribe(

      data => {
        console.log(data)
        //this.photos.push(data)
        //console.log(this.photos)
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Subscribe error: " + error)
      }
    );
  }
```

I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think you have the same problem as this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605619/angular-6-httperrorresponse-on-post-with-200-status "By default, the Angular HttpClient tries to parse the body of the HTTP response as JSON". In your backend index.js try it with `res.status(500).send({});` `res.status(200).send({});`

Comment: I tried to follow the solution what they did on that post. But when I do ``{responseType: 'text'}` after the url I just get OK back in text. My data from the backend call is not there. 
Also if I add your `res.status(200).send({});` my backend crashes and gives me this error `_http_outgoing.js:558 throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set')
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: Are you still using `res.sendStatus(...)`? The error say `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` so you cannot use both, you have to use `res.status(...).send({})` or `res.sendStatus(...)`: `if (err != null) {
          res.status(500).send({});
        } else {
          res.status(200).send({});
        }`

Comment: Oh yes, it's working. Indeed I also find out you can't use both. So I just use `res.send({data})` and now the I can get all the images out of it in the frontend! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

### updated index.js

```
app.get(
  "/getMarkerPhotos/:straatnaam/:straatnr/:postcode",
  function (req, res) {
    client.query(
      "select * from housee.houses_images where straatnaam = $1 AND straatnr = $2 AND postcode = $3",
      [req.params.straatnaam, req.params.straatnr, req.params.postcode],
      function (err, data) {
        if (err != null) {
          res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
          res.send({data});
        }
      }
    );
  }
);
```